# How to customize rails upload form and still show file that's uploaded

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulma

I'm using Rails ActiveStorage to upload photos. I've added CSS and bulma to 1) hide the rails upload form and 2) create a new custom one on top of it. But how can I also show file name once the photo is uploaded? Right now the photo uploads but does not show what's been uploaded (since the default rails form is hidden).

```html
        <div class="file" style="    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;">
        <label class="file-label">
        <span class="file-cta">
        <span class="file-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
        </span>
        <%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true, direct_upload: true, class:" ", placeholder:"Choose files", style:"    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);" %>
        <span class="file-label">
        Choose photos
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
```

I'd also really appreciate it if you could add how to do this for 1) multiple photos and also 2) show progress when uploading.

Comment: please add your existing ruby code, so that we can give advice on the errors you're getting

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this with some custom JS. Assuming, as you said, that the file is in fact uploading then it should be semi simple.

I haven't done exactly the same thing but what I have done in an application that I am presently building is render out the image as a preview once its uploaded, a quick tweak to the code should work for you!

JS:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
// Multiple images preview in browser
var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

  if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function(event) {
              $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
      }
  }

};

$('#event_banner').on('change', function() {
        $("div.event_banner").html("");
        $("div.event_banner_explanation").show();
        $("div.event_existing_banner").hide();
        $("div.event_banner").show();
  imagesPreview(this, 'div.event_banner');
});
```

With my erb being:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="event_banner_explanation" style="display:none;">
                        <p>Custom explanation text</p>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="event_banner" style="display:none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% if @event && @event.banner.attached? then %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 event_existing_banner">
                        <br>
                        <p>Current Banner image:</p>
                        <p>If you upload a new image then this one will be replaced.</p><br>
                        <% if @event.banner.id? then %>
                            <%= link_to 'Remove the image below?', delete_image_attachment_partner_event_url(@event.banner.id),
                                method: :delete,
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, style:"margin-left: 5px;" %><br>
                            <%= image_tag @event.banner, style: "max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px;" %>
                        <% else %>
                            <p>Your banner did not upload properly, please try again.</p>
                        <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

Hope that this helps, you can pull the file names in the same way and this is setup for multiple files.

For a progress bar there is a functioning example on the active storage rails page.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-upload-javascript-events